# How to identify backhand and forehand shot using accelerometer?

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope

An accelerometer has three values : x, y, z.

Let's imagine a racket has an accelerometer. if I put the racket face up, I know where are the directions of x, y and z. However, if I flip the racket and put it up side down. The value of x, y, z is in opposite directions.

In other word, if I hit the ball to x direction with my backhand, it is possible i can get positive or negative x value. (This is depending on whether I flip the racket or not [Racket has two faces]).

My question is How can the sensor tell me that I am hitting the ball using back hand but not forehand as I can get same accelerometer values for both forehand and backhand.

Thank you,
Jimmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** changed my mind about this, following @Sami's comments :)

Imagine the X and Y axes are in the plane of the racket strings (say X is along the line of the handle, Y is up/down), and Z is in the direction of hitting the ball. Then most of the acceleration when you swing & hit will be in the Z axis (+ or - depending on which face of the racket hits the ball); there's a bit of X-axis acceleration if you're swinging in an arc, but it's always in the same direction whichever face is hit. There's a constant Y-axis acceleration upwards.

[image]

So you can look at the accelerometer's Z-value to determine which face is hit, and you can look a the Y-value to tell which way up the racket is being held. From that you can tell whether the 'front' or 'back' (relative to which way the racket is oriented) is being hit, and hence tell whether a forehand or backhand shot is being played.

Of course, you'd also have to know whether the player was right or left handed :)

For a given handedness, you could calculate the type of swing as follows:

[image]

For the other handedness, the results would be reversed. The '+' and '-' values are relative to which way your accelerometer is installed, so you'd need to calibrate.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be acceleration in y direction based on the gravitational pull? Of course rotation won't cause acceleration, but it will cause change in the gravitational acceleration detected.

Comment: Acceleration is a change in velocity: ie nothing to do with gravity (unless you drop your racket!). Gravity would however be detected by an inclinometer.

Comment: I've got quite a few MEMS accelerometers here and every single one of them shows acceleration in the direction of gravity, since that's how they're made. Old phones had only an accelerometer and could very well tell the direction they're held at (just not rotation around the gravity axis). So even though acceleration is change in velocity, accelerometer's work differently.

Comment: "an accelerometer at rest on the surface of the Earth will measure an acceleration g= 9.81 m/s2 straight upwards"... you're right about that :) perhaps I should edit my answer!

Comment: The observed gravitational acceleration has nothing to do with orbiting the earth; you'd still detect it even if the earth weren't rotating.

Comment: @Sneftel: thanks for pointing that out... really what I said was wrong because we're not 'in orbit' (unless you're playing tennis on the space station). But you're correct to say that gravity, rather than the rotation of the earth, causes the observed upward acceleration. (This is turning into a physics refresher for me)

Comment: So you can look at the accelerometer's Z-value to determine which face is hit, and you can look a the Y-value to tell which way up the racket is being held. From that you can tell whether the 'front' or 'back' (relative to which way the racket is oriented) is being hit, and hence tell whether a forehand or backhand shot is being played. ----- > To me this is incorrect, because the tennis player is able to slice or spin the ball. See youtube.com/watch?v=JwMNv9JjA3Y  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wa-3GStYh_I

Comment: Maybe check Y just before the swing to determine orientation, then during the swing you can check Z: every swing will produce _some_ Z acceleration, but for slice or spin it will be mixed with some Y.

Comment: But then you are unable to identify whether the player is making a forehand shot or backhand shot. forehand topspin and backhand slice maybe provide same value.

Comment: Just before the swing, Y will tell you the orientation. During the swing, Z (together with the previous Y) tells you forehand/backhand. But during the swing Y will tell you slice/spin: a flat shot will have zero Y, but increasing amounts of slice or spin will add a larger amount of (+ or -) Y. When the racket is facing at 45 degrees to the direction of swing, the absolute values of Y and Z will be equal. Absolute Y will continue to increase (relative to Z) as the angle gets more oblique.

Answer (score 1):

There are two coordinate systems at play here: the accelerometer's and the world's. The accelerometer will have fixed x/y/z directions in its world view, but they change in relation to the world coordinates based on the orientation.

If you use the accelerometer's values as is, then you may get positive or negative impulses on hit. But when you convert them to world's coordinate system - that is, down is always towards the center of the Earth - you will always get the same values for backhand and opposite for forehand.

Let's assume that accelerometer's x direction is to the normal of the net, z is parallel to the handle and y is "up" when the racket is its normal sideways position.

Since in tennis the racket is basically on one plane (you don't hit with the net facing down, for example), and unless you're doing an overhead (in which case I think backhand is out of the question), you will always have y pointing to 1 or -1 when the racket is at rest. Simplest (but not the most accurate!) way is to check what sign y has and change x accordingly. This way you won't get the exact vectors, but you will get the information whether it was backhand or forehand.

The problem with this is also that you have to track the racket before the hit also, since if the hit isn't perfectly level (rarely is), the y acceleration will also change when the racket moves up or down while hitting and will not show the orientation of the racket at the moment of impact.

For more accurate readings you would have to determine the difference between the coordinate systems and rotate accordingly.

Comment: you will always have y pointing to 1 or -1. Simplest (but not the most accurate!) way is to check what sign y has and change x accordingly. This way you won't get the exact vectors, but you will get the information whether it was backhand or forehand. ----- > To me this is incorrect, because the tennis player is able to slice or spin the ball. See youtube.com/watch?v=JwMNv9JjA3Y  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wa-3GStYh_I

Comment: @JimmyLee That's why added the comment about tracking the racket all the time, since during the hit it will not be that simple. I'll edit it a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

For Forehand shot,
-   Y has minus gravity acceleration value and z has any value (regardless positive or negative)

For backhand shot,
-   If y has positive gravity acceleration value and z has any value (regardless positive or negative)